# Android : layout-small and layout-large

Tags: android, android-layout

I created the layout in the folder res/layout-large and res/layout-small. when I tried the emulator for the screen 5.1"WVGA 480x800 , 2.7"QVGA (240x320) and 4.65" 720p (720*1280). It always picks the layout from res/layout-small.  Please let me know how to resolve this and test the layouts

Comment: Do you have a `res/layout for normal screen sizes?

Comment: No I have some other xml in res/layout and not the one I am testing

Comment: add your xml.. may be we could help